# How to make a button in an active state by default?

Tags: javascript, css, button

I have a button like below - and I want it to be in "hover" & "focus" mode from default - the game starts on "easy" by default and therefore I want the button to be "pressed" by default which I can achieve with the classes - how do I do that?

`<button id="easyBtn"">Easy</button>`

With my classes

```
.buttons button {
  background-color: #03A9F4;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.buttons button:hover, button:focus {
  background-color: #0074a9;
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Is the autofocus what you're looking for ? <button id="easyBtn" autofocus>Easy</button>

Comment: Add a class of `button .hover` to the hover/focus definition. This way you can add that class to the button to "force" that style.

Comment: This sounds more like a job for styled radio buttons. You can used the :checked property for custom styling. Hover and focus works as with any other element

Comment: @Alexander Remember to mark an answer as accepted if you solved your problem or post your own solution as an answer to help others who may have the same issue as you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will find that radio buttons fits this job better. You can style the buttons however you want. Below is my take on the solution

```js
var currentDifficulty = 'easy';

function onDifficultyChange(e) {
    currentDifficulty = e.value;
    console.log(currentDifficulty);
}
```

```css
    [type='radio'] {
        display: none;
    }
    [type='radio'] ~ span {
        padding: 8px 16px;
        border: solid 1px royalblue;
    }
    [type='radio']:checked ~ span {
        background: royalblue;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<label>
    <input
        type="radio"
        name="difficulty"
        value="easy"
        checked
        onchange="onDifficultyChange(this)"
    />
    <span>Easy</span>
</label>
<label>
    <input
        type="radio"
        name="difficulty"
        value="medium"
        onchange="onDifficultyChange(this)"
    />
    <span>Medium</span>
</label>
<label>
    <input
        type="radio"
        name="difficulty"
        value="hard"
        onchange="onDifficultyChange(this)"
    />
    <span>Hard</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you must be storing a game difficulty as a variable, you can run something like this in your game init function:

```
document.getElementById(`button-${gameDifficulty}`).focus();
```

But like someone mentioned in the thread, it seems radio buttons should be more appropriate here.